# What's the most robust way to predict the value of some noisy time series data?

Tags: predictive-modeling, time-series

I have some time series data (time, value) such as:

```
281,97.0
284,98.0
287,98.0
290,98.0
293,98.0
297,99.0
309,100.0
320,101.0
333,101.0
346,103.0
359,104.0
372,105.0
385,107.0
396,108.0
405,108.0
```

I am trying to predict when the value will be 160.

The data is somewhat noisy. The values go mostly up, but could go down sharply every now and then, or stay the same for a short time. When these distortions occur, the prediction is far off for a period of time.

What algorithms or heuristics would work the best to deliver a robust prediction that doesn't vary to much?

I am currently using a linear fit over a time window of 60 data points. The results are not stable enough.

Comment: It is unclear to me exactly what you are asking. You fit a linear model but your description of the time series sounds quite non-linear. What is your error metric to determine best fit? You say the time series is noisy, but the example looks rather stable. Are there patterns to the discontinuities? Have you looked at ARIMA models?

Comment: Could you share with us what kind of time series we are talking about? Is it financial, biological? that's because there are certain pre-processing steps specific for different types of problems.

Comment: The data represents temperatures taken from meat cooking in the oven.